# ios 5 - EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, arrays, memory-management

See the code below. Why does accessing [self.objects count] throw this error, when the line directly before it proves that self.objects exists?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"HERE: %@", self.objects); //this logs the array - no error
    NSLog(@"num rows: %@", [self.objects count]); //this line throws the error
    return [self.objects count];
}
```

in the .h file I have this:

```
@interface YouTubeViewController_iPad : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *_objects;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *objects;
```

and in the .m file:

```
@synthesize objects = _objects;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the log string correctly:

```
NSLog(@"num rows: %@", [self.objects count]); //this line throws the error
```

[self.objects count] returns an NSInteger, which is an integer. It is important to understand that an integer is not an object.

Try this instead:

```
NSLog(@"num rows: %i", [self.objects count]); //Notice the string formatter
```

Answer (score 2):

Error at :

```
NSLog(@"num rows: %@", [self.objects count]); //this line throws the error
```

Update with :

```
NSLog(@"num rows: %d", [self.objects count]); //this line throws the error
```